# Using tar to backup and restore a path mounted with overlayfs

Tags: linux, backup, tar, openwrt, overlayfs

I have a system running OpenWRT with Linux 2.6.39.2.

In my filesystem, I have symlinks contained in */etc/rc.d* on ROM and more symlinks contained in */overlay/etc/rc.d* in flash.

overlayfs does a union mount of /overlay/etc/rc.d over /etc/rc.d.

Files in ROM that must be deleted are symlinks to *(overlay-whiteout)* stored in flash.

Citing the [OpenWRT wiki](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/flash.layout):

> Whenever the system is asked to look for an existing file in /, it first looks in /overlay, and if not there, then in /rom. In this way /overlay overrides /rom and creates the effect of a writable / while much of the content is safely and efficiently stored in the read-only /rom.
>
> When the system is asked to delete a file that is in /rom, it instead creates a corresponding entry in /overlay, a whiteout. A whiteout is a symlink to (overlay-whiteout) that mostly behaves like a file that doesn't exist.

**Performing a backup**

This is all good in theory and one could try to backup */overlay/etc/rc.d* instead of */etc/rc.d* to save both the files and the symlinks that represent a deleted file. However, whenever I extract a tar archive back to /overlay even if *(overlay-whiteout)* links are created, they are not understood by overlayfs as deleted files but as genuine links to *(overlay-whiteout)*.

What is special about these links and should I have any hope of using tar for this backup/restore procedure ?

Comment: Are you unpacking the tar archive on the same system in which the original overlayfs existed? The method used to mark deleted files in the upper directory changed at some point in the development of overlayfs. The method used in current builds does not use symbolic links, but creates a named [character device with device number 0/0](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt?v=3.18#L92).